# With statement for multiple worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I am repeating a set of actions for certain sheets in a workbook currently by

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "2015", "2016", "Rate", "Month"
        'code here
    End Select
Next ws
```

which seems awfully inefficient XD
Is it possible to do something like

```
With ws1, ws2, ws3
'code here
end with
```

I don't have that many sheets so the loop only takes ~2 seconds but there must be a quicker/elegant way?

Comment: Try using the macro recorder, selecting sheet1, holding CTRL, selecting sheet2, and typing something into A1. This is how to manually affect multiple sheets at once. Turn off the macro and look at the code - how does the code do it?

Comment: Guessing it does sheet1.select, sheet2.select?

Comment: Ahhh it does `Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Select` Will play with it thanks!

Comment: Ehhhh using .Select is not a great result (generally avoid .Select as it can complicate things quite a bit and is rarely if ever necessary) - I would keep digging online / see if someone here comes up with an answer.

Comment: If this were VB.NET, `Select` would be extremely useful here: `{"Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4"}.Select(Function(name) Worksheets(name))`. Shame.

Comment: ikr you'd think this is something that would be built in XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worksheets is a collection that contains all sheets in the current workbook.

To simplify you code you could create your own collection with just the sheets to be processed and use this instead. Then you wouldn't need the select  case statement to limit which sheets are processed by the loop.

However, seeing up a collection is probably more work than doing it the way you have done. Although it is the OO way of don't it.

So in a module you might do something like this:

```
Sub aa()
    Dim colSheets As Collection
    Set colSheets = New Collection

    colSheets.Add Sheet1  ' here I use the object name from the VBA "(Name)" property
    colSheets.Add Worksheets("MyWorksheetName")
    colSheets.Add Worksheets("SummarySheet")

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In colSheets
        Debug.Print sht.Name
    Next sht

    Set colSheets = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: More work is no good XD I can google it but if you edit to show how to set it up, I can +1

Comment: see new answer text.  I told you it would be more work.

Comment: You might like to read this [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx) also check out a video of mine [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kT3WnyYjULk) I welcome feedback.

Comment: Yea, I am familiar with class and OO. I just don't have much need for them.

Comment: What about my powerquery video? It's present using laymans terms, but it demos a lot of features

Comment: Shame.  ExcelIsFun is a channel you should have access to and WiseOwl.co.uk - very handy excel resources!  (And my video - have you got a smart phone?)

Comment: Pffft. SO forever ^_^;

Comment: can you tick it as an answer please